# Why isn't it a crime to wear a ghostface mask in public?

Tags: plot-explanation, analysis, scream-vi

In the 2023 movie, *Scream VI*, near the end of the movie the protagonists decide to meet Kirby and trap ghostface(s) in order to kill them for good.

They go by train to reach their destination. Inside the train there are many people wearing masks including ghostface mask.

My question is that why isn't it a crime to wear a ghostface mask in public while a killing spree is going on by unknown ghostface mask wearers and general security is at risk? And the consequence is that in the train that Mindy was in, the ghostface murderer stabbed her.

Also, the same question can be asked about making "stab" movies while there are murders occuring with the same costume.

Comment: I don't know entirely why you are getting downvotes, it may be because people accept minor plot holes or people being stupid for the plot of a slasher movie to happen.  Or it may be a cultural thing - it's not easy for authorities in the USA to arbitrarily make things illegal, that is rather authoritarian.

Comment: Can you add why you think it would help to make it a crime? I can’t think of how that would help. Also, are you suggesting that it would no longer be a crime after the murders are solved? How would it be made no longer a crime? That’s easier said than done.

Comment: @ToddWilcox It should be a crime or at least illegal because the real murderer can use the opportunity and hide him/herself among people who managed to wear the same costume in order to escape or even commit another crime. Also, if it shouldn't be a crime why is wearing a burka a crime for the security reasons?

Comment: Wearing a burka is also protected under the first amendment of the USA. I have just quickly looked and even in airport security you have rights to verify your identity in a private room: https://www.tsa.gov/travel/frequently-asked-questions/may-i-keep-head-coverings-and-other-religious-cultural-or#:~:text=Security%20Screening-,May%20I%20keep%20head%20coverings%20and%20other%20religious%2C%20cultural%20or,officer%20of%20the%20same%20gender.  I think you are somewhat mistaken about what is or is not illegal in the USA.

Comment: @EtackSxchange The real murderer could just as easily change clothes or costume to match anything. If blending in with the crowd is their goal, there’s no way to prevent that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The story takes place in the USA.

1. The first amendment to The Constitution guarantees freedom of speech under the law, and wearing a mask in public would almost certainly be considered protected speech.
2. Passing a law to make something a crime would take time. It would also take a majority vote of a legislating body and that might be hard to get because:
3. There’s no benefit to criminalizing a mask. It wouldn’t somehow stop the murders. It wouldn’t make the murderers easier to catch.
4. There’s no real-world history of any law like this ever being passed. For example, when white panel trucks were the suspected vehicles used by the DC area sniper, there was no outlawing of white panel trucks or anything like that. In addition, it turned out the sniper attacks were being carried out from a modified blue station wagon, not a panel truck at all. Until they have caught the killer(s), authorities in *Scream IV* can’t be sure that any specific kind of mask is involved at all.

Comment: First of all outlawing a vehicle is never practical. So with respect, your example of trucks makes no sense. Second, yes, wearing a mask is not illegal. But what if it's used for a murder? It's not bad to wear it if there is no murders or the murders are solved. But when the murders are going on it's not good to wear them. Third, I don't say the masks should be banned forever. I say they should be banned when there's a huge crime happening.

Comment: With respect, I completely disagree @EtackSxchange. Banning a vehicle that was suspected as being used in a series of crimes is a perfect example in my opinion.  They didn't ban them because they couldn't, and that it wouldn't actually make finding the criminals any easier, and in the end was found to be entirely unrelated to the crimes.  This could be easily the case for the ghost mask too.  I don't think you understand how the USA works, it would be viewed as hugely intrusive on the private individual to ban a mask like that.

Comment: Yes, people would be hugely disapproving of people making light of the murders by wearing a mask. Disapproving doesn't make it possible for it to be made illegal.

Comment: @EtackSxchange So… should clothes worn during a murder be outlawed? Shoes? When does it stop? Keep in mind that the movie is very unrealistic so it doesn’t make sense to spend too much time trying to understand any real-world concepts related to any of the *Scream* movies.  Regarding making things illegal and then making them legal again; in the United States, getting a law passed to make something legal or illegal can take months, years, or decades.

Comment: @EtackSxchange And what are you going to do to people who wear the mask, arrest them? And then what, fine them? Put them in prison? That also can take months. And for many people they are allowed out of jail while they wait for trial, so you wouldn’t be stopping any murders even if you could make it illegal. Again, I ask what possible benefit there could be to making it illegal to wear a mask

Comment: Even if you could ban and imprison people wearing them without due legal process - what would it achieve?  Overnight, no-one, including the murderer would wear them.  You still have to work out who is actually the murderer.